# How to add double quote characters to a string?

Tags: lua

How can I add double quote characters to a given string?

```
local str = "foo"
```

How can I get the string `"foo"` where the string contains a leading and trailing quote `"`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understood your question, you can do it in a few different ways.

1. Use escaped double quote:

   ```
   function quote(str)
       return "\""..str.."\""
   end
   ```
2. Use single quote to use double quote character without escaping:

   ```
   function quote2(str)
       return '"'..str..'"'
   end
   ```

Answer (score 9):

You can just glue the quote to the string:

```
local str = "foo"

print('"' .. foo .. '"') --> "foo"
print("\"" .. foo .. "\"") --> "foo"
print([["]] .. foo .. [["]]) --> "foo"
```

But if you're constructing data for machine consumption (e.g. for serialization), you want to escape quotes and other funny characters that may be inside the string. Use `"%q"` format specifier for this:

```
local str = 'f"o"o'

print(string.format("%q", str)) --> "f\"o\"o"
```

In shorter form:

```
print(("%q"):format(str)) --> "f\"o\"o"
```

Comment: `attempt to call global 'string' (a table value)`, hmm?

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you would like to both escape and quote:

```
function string.quote(str)
  return '"' .. str:gsub('\\', '\\\\'):gsub('"', '\\"') .. '"'
end

local a = '"Hello again \\ to all my friends"'

print(a:quote())
```

Which will give you the following string:

```
"\"Hello again \\ to all my friends\""
```