# Lua issues with string containing double and/or single quotes - string.format("%q") suffixes with \13

Tags: lua, double-quotes, string.format, single-quotes

In lua,
I'm reading a text file, which lines may contain single or double quotes such as:
"L'habitude commence comme un fil de soie et devient vite un câble d'acier" - Proverbe espagnol

the lines are used as such:

```
local cmd = 'zenity --question --no-wrap  --title "pause" --text ' .. string.format("%q", quote)
print (cmd)
local retVal = os.execute(cmd)
```

Everything works fine, but at the very end of string there the character \13 is suffixed to the string, which I do not want.

```
zenity --question --no-wrap --title "pause" --text "L'habitude commence comme un fil de soie et devient vite un câble d'acier. - Proverbe espagnol\13"
```

And zenity windows displays this \13 char.

How to solve this?

Thanks

Related:
[How to add double quote characters to a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5305412/how-to-add-double-quote-characters-to-a-string)

Answer (score 1):

Your quote contains a carriage return. Carriage return is not a printable character. How should Lua quote a non-printable character?

From the [Lua 5.4 Reference Manual: string.format](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-string.format)

> The specifier q formats booleans, nil, numbers, and strings in a way
> that the result is a valid constant in Lua source code. Booleans and
> nil are written in the obvious way (true, false, nil). Floats are
> written in hexadecimal, to preserve full precision. A string is
> written between double quotes, using escape sequences when necessary
> to ensure that it can safely be read back by the Lua interpreter. For
> instance, the call
>
> ```
>  string.format('%q', 'a string with "quotes" and \n new line')
> ```
>
> may produce the string:
>
> ```
>  "a string with \"quotes\" and \
>   new line"
> ```

Remove it if you don't want it to end up in your string as `\13`.

You can use `string.sub` to remove it. Multiple carriage returns are best removed using `string.gsub`.

Alternatively use `string.format('"%s"', quote)` or `string.format("\"%s\"", quote)`. There's even more ways to write double quotes in a string.

Comment: string.format('"%s"', quote) 
It works

>There's even more ways to write double quotes in a string.
Want to know more

Comment: Instead of string.format you can use the concatenation operator. `print("\""..quote.."\"")` or `print('"' .. quote .. '"')`  or `print([["]]..quote..[["]])` ...

Comment: Yes, but these didn't worked, as some sentences already contain single & double quotes

Answer (score -1):

Your original text ended with `\13`, a CR. Remove it with

```
quote = quote:sub(quote,1,-2)
```

If the string might not end with a CR, then remove it if present with

```
quote = quote:gsub("\13$","")
```

Comment: Humm, then I ought to test if there is indeed a CR in the string.